# Disable next form field on dynamically inserted form elements

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked  many times before but none of those solutions seem to work in my situation.

I need the checkbox on each row to disable the next text field. Each table row is created on the fly (JS clone). Only the first row is static. Each subsequent row, the name and ID are appended with a new number (formfield1, formfield2, etc) and happen after the page has loaded.

HTML

```
    <div class="add_rec_container" id="fuel_stop" style="display:block;"><!--open #fuel_stop-->
    <p class="label">Enter Fuel Stop:</p>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="fuel_stop_table" class="fuel_data">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><select name="data_fuel_state1" id="data_fuel_state1" class="state_menu">
            <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
            <option value="CA" selected="selected">CA</option>
            <option value="NM">NM</option>
            <option value="NV">NV</option>
            <option value="OR">OR</option>
            <option value="UT">UT</option>
            </select>
            </td>
          <td><input type="tel" name="data_total_gal1" id="data_total_gal1" class="help total_gal_field" title="Gallons"/></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="data_yard1" id="data_yard1" class="enablePPG" value="yes" onclick="disablePPG(this);"/> Yard
          </td>
          <td>$ <input type="tel" name="data_price1" id="data_price1" class="help price_field" title="PPG" /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a id="add_fuel_row" class="add_btn">+ State</a>
    </div><!--close #fuel_stop-->

  <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="send_button" value="Send"/>
</form>​
</div><!--close .record_entry_container-->
```

JS (not working but I think should)

```
function disablePPG() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).next('.price_field').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
        $(this).next('.price_field').prop('disabled', false);
      }
  });
}
```

The following JS works on the first row of form elements, but obviously not a solution for multiple rows when added.

```
function disablePPG() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($('#data_yard1').is(':checked')) {
      $('#data_price1').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#data_price1').prop('disabled', false);      
    }
  });
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".enablePPG").on("click", function()
{
    if($(this).is(":checked") == true)
        $(this).parent().next().children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else
        $(this).parent().next().children().removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately not a solution. It does not disable the any of the fields.

Comment: @macericpet I just tested it and it works on the latest version of jQuery

Comment: Using 1.7.1. Let me check if using the newest breaks other scripts. Thanks.

Comment: Just tested with 1.10.1 and it still did not work (also it broke all other JS on the page/site) so that is not an option. I will have to look at other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: @macericpet replace "on" with "live" and it should work with 1.7.1